# Implementação de foreach

Tags: php, xml

```
<?php

$busca = $_GET['genero'];

$xml_string = file_get_contents("livros.xml");
$xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

for ($i=0; $i < count($xml_object->livro); $i++) { 

    for ($j=0; $j < count($xml_object->livro[$i]->genero->descricao); $j++) { 

        if($busca == $xml_object->livro[$i]->genero->descricao[$j]){

            echo $xml_object->livro[$i]->titulo."<br>";
            echo $xml_object->livro[$i]->genero->descricao."<br>";
            echo $xml_object->livro[$i]->isbn."<br>";
            echo $xml_object->livro[$i]->autor."<br>";
            echo $xml_object->livro[$i]->publicacao."<br>";
            echo fLocalMostraGenero($xml_object->livro[$i])."<br>";
        }
    }

    $xml_object->livro[$i]->titulo;

}

function fLocalMostraGenero($livro){

    for($i = 0; $i < count($livro->genero->descricao); $i++)

    {
        echo $livro->genero->descricao[$i];
    }
}
```

Fiz esse código para a realizar uma busca por gênero dentro um xml. Um colega me falou para usar o foreach no lugar do meu for normal, mas eu não entendi muito bem como ele funciona e como fazer essa troca no meu código. Alguém pode me dar uma explicação?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta pergunta do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637617/how-to-use-foreach-with-php-xml-simplexml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, o foreach no php tem a segunte sintaxe:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

Por exemplo:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

Quando tu usa um foreach, ele faz um loop por todos os elementos do array, um por um. No código exemplo, a cada passada do loop, `$value` é um dos elementos do array. Nesse caso, multiplicaria por dois todos os elementos do array `$arr`

Answer (score 0):

No php, o foreach funciona de seguinte forma

```
foreach(array as [key] => value){

}
```

Onde: array => o array que você quer percorrer
key => posição no array que está percorrendo
value => o valor que tem dentro do array.

Por exemplo, temos um array com os seguintes dados

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

Para pegar esses dados, faremos

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
      //se dermos um echo no $value, temos a seguinte forma
      echo $value->foo

}
```

No exemplo acima irá apresentar o valor "bar", lembrando que para acessar no php usamos o "->"

Para mais informações use o [Seguinte link](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)